# How do i find the 'from' Chart version at a helm upgrade?

Tags: upgrade, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm built in object 'Release.isUpgrade' to ensure an init-container is only run at upgrade.

I want to only run the init-container when upgrading from a specific Chart version.

Is it possible to get the 'from' Chart version in a helm upgrade ?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like this information is published either in [the `.Release` object](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/builtin_objects/) or through information available to a [hook job](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/).

You probably want a pre-upgrade hook and not an init container.  If you have multiple replicas on your deployments, the init container will run on all of them; even if you have just one, if the node it's on fails and is replaced, the replacement will re-run the init container.  A pre-upgrade hook will run just once, regardless of how the corresponding deployments are configured.

That hook will be a separate pod (and will require writing code), so within that you can do whatever you want.  You can give it read access to the Kubernetes API to get the definition of an existing deployment, for example, and then look at its labels or container image tag to find out what version of the chart/application is running now.  (There are [standard labels](https://docs.helm.sh/docs/chart_best_practices/labels/#standard-labels) that can help with this.)  You could also make the upgrade step just look for its own outputs: if object X is supposed to exist, create it if it's not there, without focusing on specific versions.